# Why do Table view cels get selected each time they appear while scrolling, after overriding the custom cell's setSelected method?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I tried to make a custom animation for table view cell selection, so I've overridden the custom cell's setSelected method with this code:

```
  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    if self.frame.size.height == 132{
        self.backgroundViewTop.constant = 40
        UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 0.08, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {
            self.backView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.891, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1)
        }, completion: { finished in
            UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {
                self.backView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }, completion: nil )
        })
    }else{
        self.backgroundViewTop.constant = 0
        UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 0.08, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {
            self.backView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.891, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1)
        }, completion: { finished in
            UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {
                self.backView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }, completion: nil )
        })
    }
```

}

Now, when I scroll and new cells appear on the screen, this animation happens. Why does this method get called, and is overridding it the proper way to achieve custom animation on selection?

Comment: When you override a function you must call the super function of the super class and then do your things.
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
..
}

Comment: I did it, but there's still the same issue.

Comment: I looks like `selected` is set to `false` when the table first loads. You might want to add an `if selected { ... }` check if you only want the  animation to appear when the cell is selected.

Comment: @DennisW. Thank you very much. That fixed this issue. Although I still don't understand why and when this method actually gets called. :D

Comment: @Andre3000 it looks like it is called as part of the cell's `super class` initializer.

Comment: @DennisW yes, but then how come it's not the default behaviour?